# Java Parse String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String in a following format:

```
 {"id":"1263e246711d665a1fc48f09","facebook_username":"","google_username":"814234576543213456788"}
```

but sometimes this string looks like:

```
{"id":"1263e246711d665a1fc48f09","facebook_username":"109774662140688764736","google_username":""}
```

How can I extract those values if I do not know the index of substrings as they will change for different cases?

Comment: This is a JSON String. Instead of parsing it, find a JSON library that will generate a `JSONObject` from this string. If you are using Java EE 7 and higher, you can look at the JSON-P framework.

Comment: I solved this problem in really easy way altough I belive that GaruGaru's answer is correct. ` json = new JSONObject(JsonResponse);
                   String myID = json.getString("id"); String googleUserName = json.getString("google_username");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like json format, you should give a look to the [Gson library](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.6.2%7C) by google that will parse that string automatically.

Your class should look like this

```
public class Data
{
private String id;

private String facebook_username;

private String google_username;
// getters / setters...
}
```

And then you can simply create a function that create the object from the json string:

```
Data getDataFromJson(String json){
     return (Data) new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

That String is formated in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). Is a common language used to transfer data.

You can parse it using Google's library Gson, just add it to your class path .

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //convert the json string back to object
    DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class); //The object you want to convert to.
```

https://github.com/google/gson

[Check this out on how to convert to Java Object](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing as JSON notwithstanding, here's a pure string-based solution:

```
String id = str.replaceAll(".*\"id\":\"(.*?)\".*", "$1");
```

And similar for the other two, swapping `id` for the other field names.